# How to convert SSRS 2005 report to a higher version (SSRS 2010 or later) programmatically?

Tags: reporting-services, upgrade, reportingservices-2005

I am using SSRS 2005 in an old project, it has been working perfect with ReportViewer in local mode for many years, but recently I encountered an exception while exporting the excel report. ".xls" file has a max rows limit (65536), I decide to upgrade the SSRS to a higher version.

Since many years past, there generated thousands of reports, the report definitions were saved as XML in the database. I tried to load the old report definition with ReportViewer 2010 (SQL Server 2008 r2), but failed.

After some research, I know it is easily to convert RDL 2005 to RDL 2010 by opening the report in Visual Studio, it did work as expected.

Is there a library or command line tool to convert RDL 2005 to RDL 2010?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to rewrite the logic creating SSRS Report, basically it is translating business logic to a xml string.
BTW, I got this repository: [dynamic-rdlc](http://ttps://github.com/osnoser1/dynamic-rdlc), it is much easier.